# How can I set values to an object returned by Linq to Entities without using an anonymous?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

I need to return an `IQueryable` that will be fetching data from an `Entity Framework 6` database.

So far, I have a query like this:

```
from i in dbContext.Instruments
where i.EquipID.Equals(equip.ID)
join r in dbContext.Readings on i.ID equals r.InstrumentID into rs
from r in rs.DefaultIfEmpty()
group r by i into g
select ...;
```

I know I could use the following as the `select` portion, but then anonymous objects are returned:

```
select new
{
    g.Key.ID,
    g.Key.Name,
    g.Key.InstrumentType,
    g.Key.Units,
    g.Key.RollOver,
    g.Key.LastReading = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateOfReading).FirstOrDefault().Value,
    g.Key.LastReadingDate = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateOfReading).FirstOrDefault().DateOfReading,
}
```

What's important are the last two properties, where values are set on-the-fly.  I need the objects held by `g.Key`, with the properties `LastReading` and `LastReadingDate` set.

Is it possible to have a navigation property that is the result of a (sub) query, instead of an object derived by a foreign key?  If so, how could I work that into my query?

Some additional thoughts...

Anonymous objects won't work because I need the actual Entity class objects later on.  I can't use `new Instrument()` because that threw an exception (complex Entity type cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query).  I also cannot use something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2270816/1633308), because the query is going through Entity, and the method would not translate to an SQL statement.

Comment: Why not just create a class to contain the results? You can use `select new ContainerClass {` in just the same way as `select new {`

Comment: @stuartd For the same reason that anonymous objects won't work, I need the Entities to come through to the result set because they are used directly from that point forward.  The IQueryable this produces is used as a data source for a grid control, and the grid rows are the entities.

Comment: Your query can't return entities though and include the data you want. Which entity do you need, `Instruments` or `Readings`?

Comment: @NetMage I need the `Instrument` entity to come through.  That is what `g.Key` holds.  That model class has an extra set of parameters for `LastReading` and `LastReadingDate`.  Those values come from the `Reading` that is the `groupby`.  The properties are marked with a `[NotMapped]` attribute.